# ms sql resource management using bluebird promises

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm using the mssql module to connect to a sql server database using node. Bluebird has a feature that's similar to resource management in c#. It has a 'using' method to avoid having to use try/catch/finall to dispose of the resources. They have examples for pg and mysql, but they don't have an example for mssql which doesn't create a connection the same way as pg and mysql. Here's an example of how to use it:

```
using(getConnection(),
  fs.readFileAsync("file.sql", "utf8"), function(connection, fileContents) {
  return connection.query(fileContents);
}).then(function() {
  console.log("query successful and connection closed");
});
```

But to be able to use this method, you need to create a connection method which describes how to close the connection. Here's an example for pg:

```
function getSqlConnection(connectionString) {
   var close;
   return pg.connectAsync(connectionString).spread(function(client, done) {
      close = done;
      return client;
   }).disposer(function(client) {
      if (close) close(client);
   });
}
```

The problem I'm having with mssql module is that the connect method doesn't return a connection object like pg or even the mysql module. Has anyone been able to do this with mssql?

**Update 1:**

Here's how I made the transaction disposer:

```
function getTransaction(connection) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       var tx = sql.Transaction(connection);
       tx.beginAsync().then(function(err) {
           if(err) {
             tx = null;
             return reject(err);
           }
           return resolve(tx);
       });
   }).disposer(function(tx, promise) {
       if(promise.isFulfilled()) {
          return tx.commitAsync();
       }
       else {
          return tx.rollbackAsync();
       }
   });
}
```

It seems to be working, but not sure if this is efficient. Now I need to figure out how to catch errors on a query.

This is how I'm doing a transaction:

```
using(getConnection(), function(connection) {
   return using(getTransaction(connection), function(tx) {
          return query(queryString, tx).then(function() {
               console.log('first query in transaction completed.');
               console.log('starting second query in transaction.');
               return query(anotherQueryString, tx);
          });
   });
});
```

If I tag a single catch to the outer 'using', will that catch all errors from the whole transaction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question, mssql has really tricky API (constructors taking callbacks!) so this is good addition to the documentation.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var sql = Promise.promisifyAll(require("mssql"));
global.using = Promise.using;

function getConnection(config) {
    var connection;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) 
        connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                connection = null;
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(connection);
        });
    }).disposer(function() {
      if (connection) connection.close();
   });
}

var config = {
    user: '...',
    password: '...',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: '...',
};

using(getConnection(config), function(connection) {
    var request = new sql.Request(connection);
    return request.queryAsync("select 1 as number").then(function(recordSet) {
        console.log("got record set", recordSet);
        return request.queryAsync("select 10 as number");
    });
}).then(function(recordSet) {
    console.log("got record set", recordSet);
})
```

To use the transaction, try implementing getTransaction like:

```
function getTransaction(connection) {
  var tx = new sql.Transaction(connection);
  return tx.beginAsync().thenReturn(tx).disposer(function(tx, promise) {
    return promise.isFulfilled() ? tx.commitAsync() : tx.rollbackAsync();
  });
}
```

And using it like:

```
using(getConnection(), function(connection) {
  return using(getTransaction(connection), function(tx) {
    var request = new sql.Request(tx);
    return request.queryAsync("INSERT 1...").then(function() {
      return request.queryAsync("INSERT 2...");
    }).then(function() {
      return request.queryAsync("INSERT 3...");
    });
  });
});
```

Error handling:

```
using(getConnection(), function(connection) {
  return using(getTransaction(connection), function(tx) {
    var request = new sql.Request(tx);
    return request.queryAsync("INSERT...");
  });
}).catch(sql.TransactionError, function(e) {
  console.log("transaction failed", e);
}).catch(sql.ConnectionError, function(e) {
  console.log("connection failed", e);
}).catch(sql.RequestError, function(e) {
  console.log("invalid query", e);
});
```

Comment: Hmm, I'll give that a shot. Just curious why you're promisifying all mssql but then you don't use the promises? Example: you're calling connection.close() instead of connection.closeAsync(). Also, can you show me a way to integrate transactions in your example? I can see how the 'using' statement would really come in handy for transactions.

Comment: @u84six because `close` is a synchronous method

Comment: I'm still kind of struggling to get the transaction disposer working (with commit, rollback). When I use the nested 'using' statements (the first one being getConnection and the second being getTransaction), the first 'using' completes before the nested one starts (hence the async nature of node). Do you know of a way I can create the 'using' statement for transaction?

Comment: @u84six can you make a separate question with the code? Also are you sure you are just not forgetting `return`?

Comment: You don't have much error checking in your examples. beginAsync() can pass in an error. How can I catch all errors in a complete transaction?

Comment: @u84six Errors propagate automatically through the chain, which can be caught using `.catch(ErrorType, function(e){})` for example

Comment: I need to keep reminding myself that I don't need to create a new promise if I'm using functions that are already promisified. Getting my head around this after using callbacks is a mild challenge.

Comment: I need to keep the error types wrapped so that I can drop another db in if I want. Maybe I should handle the specific errors in the 'get' methods and just have the 'using' return a generic failure.

Comment: @u84six the error types don't have to be error types, they can be generic predicate functions. See https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#catchfunction-errorclassfunction-predicate-function-handler---promise

Comment: can you update your transaction example with 3 separate queries? I'm having trouble getting this to work. My code seems way too long.

Comment: Wow, all those returns make it so confusing. Instead of callback hell, now we have return hell. ; )

Comment: If you use coffeescript or es6 arrow functions the return statement is implicit

Comment: I'm wondering why you're promisifying mssql module, when it already supports promises? https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#promises